# ZXing Read 1D barcodes iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I know that the ZXing library for iOS reads only QR codes, but is there a version or port somewhere that reads 1d barcodes as well?

I can't seem to find one that is working currently.

Answer (score 2):

The ZXing port for iOS does decode more than QR codes. For example, the Data Matrix port is up to date.

The 1D code support is not strong. You can turn 1D support on (look at the ScanTest code for an example how) and it will decode many 1D codes, but not as reliably as the Java port. (Use the code in svn or the git mirror if you do this; there's been a patch to fix a crash since the last release).

There's no port of ZXing that does better than this. No one has stepped up to help keep the 1D code in as good of shape in C++ as it is in Java.

It's not clear from the question if you're open to other open source libraries that might have better 1D suport. [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) is the primary alternative.

Comment: I don't understand from anywhere if porting the java 1d bar scanner library code to cpp for iPhone, is a lot of work.. or just few classes to convert

Answer (score 1):

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) iphone: iPhone client + port to Objective C / C++ (QR code only)

But someone did this [here](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC)

Have fun